# dtexec error "The connection xxx is not found" with Project deployment model

Tags: ssis, dtexec

When running DTEXEC I am getting "The connection xxxx is not found".

I beleieve this is because the connection managers are located at Project level and not within the package itself.

When running DTEXECUI - these connection managers are not displayed.

Is the only way to move them into the package - seems a bit weird as what is the point of allowing them a project level if you then have to move them to use them with DTEXEC.

Thanks

Here is the command line syntax you asked for:

C:\Users\Administrator>dtexec /FILE "\"F:\SSIS Projects\HESA\HESA\01 - Upload Metadata Files To Oracle.dtsx\"" /SET "\Package.Variables[User::varYear.Properties
[Value]";"1999" /CHECKPOINTING OFF  /REPORTING EW /CONSOLELOG SMT

Comment: Could you update your question with the exact syntax you are using to call dtexec?

Comment: Here is the command line syntax you asked for:

C:\Users\Administrator>dtexec /FILE "\"F:\SSIS Projects\HESA\HESA\01 - Upload Metadata Files To Oracle.dtsx\"" /SET "\Package.Variables[User::varYear.Properties [Value]";"1999" /CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING EW /CONSOLELOG SMT

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption that

> the connection managers are located at Project level and not within the package itself

is exactly the problem. But there is a solution:

- build the project to get a `.ispac` file
- instead of invoking `dtexec` with `/FILE` you have to invoke it with `/Project` and `/Package`, like this:

  ```
  /Project "path to you .ispac file, resulting from building the project"
  /Package "Name of your package.dtsx"
  ```

Please, be aware that if you provide the whole path to your `.dtsx` package the execution will fail with very criptic `SQLDUMPER` error messages.